# How to remove a user from recipients of Jenkins build failure email

Tags: email, jenkins, notifications

I'm receiving daily "Jenkins build is unstable" emails for a project I'm no longer working on.

I can see from the build result (build.xml) that I'm in the list of "culprits", because of a commit I made some time ago, and since the build has been unstable for weeks, the list of culprits hasn't been cleared.

Since I'm no longer working on this project, I want to stop receiving email notifications from this Jenkins job. How can I remove myself from the recipients? Should I edit the build.xml of the last build? *(EDIT: apparently this approach doesn't work)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just spam filter/block the email by title in your email client? Most Jenkins build emails will have a common title (with different only in status, build number). Builds from different jobs will have different common titles. So block the "offending" email by title.

To get Jenkins to 'release' you from the culprits, the build has to succeed. If you have access to the job configuration, you can make a fake success build (a simple "exit 0" in the command line will suffice), but this will clear all other culprits too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I'll have to harass my former team mates until they fix the build ;)

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question though, which I'm trying to do: `How to remove a user from recipients of Jenkins build failure email`

Comment: For the answer to the OP, read the second paragraph of my answer. If you have a different question, please post a different question. The emails are configured either explicit, or implicit through commits. If explicit, edit configuration and remove explicit email address. If implicit,  turn off notification to committers, but that will affect **all** committers. You cannot have implicit email notification to committers, and exclude specific users.

Answer (score 4):

It *is* possible, but a little complicated. First, you need to stop Jenkins or send it to quiet mode to avoid further builds.

As the actual list of culprits is calculated at runtime from all recently failed builds, you need to remove your ID from the culprits list in the build.xml of all failed builds (since the last successful one) where it is listed.

Finally restart Jenkins so the internal data structure is updated from the modified build.xmls.

So, if build 10 was the last successful one, you need to remove the ID from builds/11/build.xml, builds/12/build.xml, etc.